how to search column for multiple strings in R
I have a list of characters and I would like to search for them and a create a column for them in R.
antifungals <- c("caspofungin", "fluconazole") 
Here is an example:
Original dataframe:



patient
drug name




1
caspofungin


2
fluconazole


2
fluconazole


3
amoxicillin



Desired dataframe:



patient
drug name
category




1
caspofungin
antifungal


2
fluconazole
antifungal


2
fluconazole
antifungal


3
amoxicillin





Are there other categories?

A dplyr approach would be like this:
df <- data.frame(
  patient = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
  drug_name = c("caspofungin","fluconazole", "fluconazole", "amoxicillin")
)

library(dplyr)
antifungals <- c("caspofungin", "fluconazole")
df %>%
  mutate(
    category = ifelse(drug_name %in% antifungals, "antifungal", "")
  )

  patient   drug_name   category
1       1 caspofungin antifungal
2       2 fluconazole antifungal
3       2 fluconazole antifungal
4       3 amoxicillin           


From antifungals create a named list L and from that a Category tibble. Then left join it to the Patient data.frame by category. Category is constructed in such a way that additional categories can be added as discussed further down.
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

L <- lst(antifungals) ##

Category <- L %>%
  enframe(name = "category", value = "drug name") %>%
  unnest(`drug name`)

Patient %>%
  left_join(Category, by = "drug name")
##   patient   drug name    category
## 1       1 caspofungin antifungals
## 2       2 fluconazole antifungals
## 3       2 fluconazole antifungals
## 4       3 amoxicillin        <NA>

If we had more categories just replace the line defining L (marked ## above) with a longer list like this:
antifungals <- c("caspofungin", "fluconazole")
antibiotics <- c("amoxicillin", "erythromycin", "tetracycline")
L <- lst(antifungals, antibiotics)

Note
Inputs in reproducible form:
Lines <- 'patient "drug name"
1 caspofungin
2 fluconazole
2 fluconazole
3 amoxicillin'
Patient <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

antifungals <- c("caspofungin", "fluconazole")


You could create regex patterns, separated with an | (or).
> (antifungals <- c("caspofungin", "fluconazole") |> paste(collapse='|'))
[1] "caspofungin|fluconazole"
> antibiotic <- c('amoxicillin') |> paste(collapse='|')

Then use stringi::stri_replace_all_regex().
> dat |> 
+   transform(
+     category=stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
+       drug_name,
+       c(antifungals, antibiotic),
+       c('antifungals', 'antibiotics'),
+       vectorize_all=FALSE
+     )
+   )
  patient   drug_name    category
1       1 caspofungin antifungals
2       2 fluconazole antifungals
3       2 fluconazole antifungals
4       3 amoxicillin antibiotics


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(patient = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), drug_name = c("caspofungin", 
"fluconazole", "fluconazole", "amoxicillin")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

